# Google Analytics Page Title Regex for "Page Title Contains Exact String"?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm looking for REGEX that excludes Page Titles that contain 'car' but doens't exclude page titles that include 'cars'.

I've tried ^car$ with no success.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is better to use Include 'cars'?